# How can I use Rules to publish nodes depending on changing the value in a Field?

Tags: entities, nodes, rules

I would like to set up rule to detect if I change one specific field in the content type.  For example if I choose the field "dyzury", then the rule will publish this node to the front page with the new value in the field.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the rule to fire on the event *Before saving content* so you will have both values of the field available.

Set the conditions as follows:

1. *Node is of type* and select your content type.
2. AND *Entity is new*. Your data selector should be `Node` and negate the condition (NOT new)
3. AND *Entity has field*, Again your data selector should be `Node` and select your field_dyzury from the drop-down list to make the field available to the rule.
4. AND *Data comparision* and using data selectors for both values choose `[node-unchanged:field-dyzury]` and `[node:field-dyzury]`. Select the `Equals` operator and negate the condition (NOT equal)

It is important to detect that the node is not new, or there will be no existing data value for the comparison.

Then set the Action to *Promote content to front page*. Again, data selector should be `Node`.

This rule will detect any change in field_dyzury, and will promote the content to the front page when a change is detected.

Edit:

The conditions should look like:

```
+ Content is of Type
+ AND
    + NOT Entity is new
+ AND
    + Entity has field
+ AND
    + NOT Data comparison
```

The AND's force the rule to require ALL of the conditions to evaluate to true before the actions are performed.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But it is a problem :( If I don't change the field this solutions make an action :( Could you check if I have done fine every configuration? http://150.254.36.80/wige/sites/default/files/Snap_2013.06.02_21h54m17s_001__0.png

Comment: You forgot the AND's.

Comment: Just had a look at your new screenshot, and it looks fine, but you should keep it simple for testing (just one action, say 'Promote to front page'). Did you select the Equals operator in your Data comparison condition? If you go into publishing options and uncheck the 'Promote to front page' (no other changes), is the node removed from the front page when you save it? Also did you clear your caches?

Comment: Not familiar with your Drupal language distribution. The pipe symbol '|' I am assuming is being produced when you select 'Dodaj and'.

Comment: I=AND I attach a screenshot of not Data comparison http://150.254.36.80/wige/sites/default/files/Snap_2013.06.02_23h23m08s_003_.png It doesn't work after I cleared my caches

Comment: the node isn't removed from the front page if I save without changes :( If I try to not publish to the ftont page I can do it. It seems as this action is every time performed when I save my content type :(

Comment: You are using Direct Input mode which will not work. Redo the Data comparison condition, but this time make sure you use the Data Selector mode. Use data selectors to get the value of a field. Use Direct input to enter a value. If you wanted to test if a field was equal to '3', then you would use Direct input to enter the required value. In this case you want to compare the stored value and the new value of a field. You need data selectors. (Recheck all your conditions and make sure they use data selectors.)

Comment: It works :) Thank you!! You are great!! Could you tell me how I can set a new value of field_strefy_dodatkowe it is a taxonony term (strefy) I would like to set a term "tak". There is a taxonomy term "strefy" and in strefy a vocabulary: "tak"

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck, but that is a new question and should be posted as such.