# Determine conditions for Rules when changing field value

Tags: 7, users, rules

I've a Rule with below specification

**Events:**
`After updating an existing user account`

**Conditions:**
`???`

**Actions**
`Create a Message`

But I don't know how can I set a condition on field in rule condition part that return true when the field changed,any body know how can I add condition on specified field that return true when the field changed?

Comment: Hello. Could you try to write your question again? I can't figure what you need. I guess you are not English native speaker. That's fine, neither am I, but we need to put an extra level of care to make our questions understandable for wider audience - and thus answerable.

Comment: how can i create rules condition for event when changed value of field !? EX: when user change avatar @Molot

Comment: Possibly related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/93997/16495 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/74956/16495 Maybe this one is duplicate of one of them, but I still don't quite understand. Or I don't know if I understood.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create the rule for **Before saving content** rather than **After saving content**.

**Before saving content** has both the original node values and the new updated values which allows you to compare the values.

**After saving content** only has the updated values, so you won't be able to see what the old values are.

Answer (score 1):

Condition: **Data comparison**

**DATA TO COMPARE**

In **Data selector** you have two different states "*account (updated user)*" and "*account-unchanged (unchanged user)*".
Check field from *account (updated user)* and click "Continue".

On next screen click "Switch to data selection" button and find your field but from *account-unchanged* state.

Select **Value** to *equals* and don't forget to check "Negate" at very bottom.